# Google reCaptcha doesn't show captcha challenge dialog on a real device

Tags: android, recaptcha, safetynet

I'm trying to implement google reCaptcha following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha) from google developers site. My code:

```
private fun onClick() {
    SafetyNet.getClient(this).verifyWithRecaptcha(CAPTCHA_KEY)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this) { response ->
                if (!response.tokenResult.isEmpty()) {
                    verify(response.tokenResult)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
                if (e is ApiException) {
                    Log.d("asd", "Error message: " + CommonStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(e.statusCode))
                } else {
                    Log.d("asd", "Unknown type of error: " + e.message)
                }
            }
}
```

On emulator its work fine. When i click on button, reCaptcha show dialogs with several images where user should pick all images with cars, gidrants etc.

But, on real device. After i click on button, i always receive onSuccess callback, and the dialog never shown.

Maybe somebody know what the problem i faced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetClient):

> If reCAPTCHA is confident that this is a real user on a real device it will return a token with no challenge. Otherwise it will provide a visual/audio challenge to attest the humanness of the user before returning a token.

"No challenge" means no reCAPTCHA. With reference to your real device, Google is apparently already satisified as to your humanness, and does not require further confirmation.

`verifyWithRecaptcha()` is operating as designed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @greeble31 can you tell how reCAPTCHA  decides on the device it's real user

Comment: @AndoMasahashi I could only guess.

Comment: Can you please share your thoughts

Comment: @AndoMasahashi Perhaps Google uses the result of a series of human intelligence challenges to build up a profile, which is tracked based on IP address in conjunction with a pseudonymous identifier (cookie or mobile advertising ID). If their server believes the client is likely human, based on this profile, then there's no need for a reCAPTCHA; the client will be issued an authentication token directly.